# Why am I receiving an error when installing PEAR?

Tags: php, pear

I am trying to install PEAR for use with PHP. As i read on the installation instructions at http://pear.php.net/manual/en/installation.getting.php
, I am supposed to run the file go-pear.bat which I have in my C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.3.0 directory. According to all the installation guides I have read, it should install and ask me a series of installation questions, but I am receiving the following error:

**phar "C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.3.0\PEAR\go-pear.phar" does not have a signature
PHP Warning: require_once(phar://go-pear.par/index.php): failed to open stream: phar error: invalid url or non-existent phar "phar://go-pear.phar/index.php" in C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.3.0\PEAR\go-pear.phar on line 1236**

**Warning: require_once(phar://go-pear.par/index.php): failed to open stream: phar error: invalid url or non-existent phar "phar://go-pear.phar/index.php" in C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.3.0\PEAR\go-pear.phar on line 1236
Press any key to continue...**

I'm not sure why I am receiving this error. I just installed the new Wampserver recently.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Maybe [this is](http://www.mattrefghi.com/wordpress/2009/10/go-pear-phar-does-not-have-a-signature/) what you are looking for.

Here are the steps:

> 1) Locate the "php.ini" file.  In my
>   case, I found it at this path:
>
> C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.3.0\php.ini
>
> Don't use the WAMP system tray icon to
>   edit this file. It didn't work when I
>   tried - you have to manually locate
>   it.
>
> 2) Find the following line, in bold:
>
> ;
>   http://php.net/phar.require-hash;phar.require_hash
>   = On ; http://php.net/phar.require-hash
>
> ;phar.require_hash = On
>
> 3) Uncomment the ";phar.require_hash =
>   On" line by removing the semi-colon.
>
> 4) Change "On" to "Off".
>
> ; http://php.net/phar.require-hash
>
> phar.require_hash = Off
>
> 5) Save the file.
>
> After I performed those steps,
>   "go-pear.bat"  began working normally
>   again.

Comment: WOW! That was it! Thanks you so very much! I was pulling my hair out over this! Do you know why this was happening? I'm surprised more people haven't had this problem.

Comment: This did it for me as well. Note that in my version, php 5.3.5, bundled with the ZendServer CE package, the line _phar.require_hash = Off_ wasnt in the php.ini at all and had to be added.

Comment: I had no [phar] section in my php.ini at all. Just added the section "[phar]" with single line "phar.require_hash = Off" and it works! Thanks )

Comment: also, is good to follow these steps in WAMP: http://phphints.wordpress.com/2008/08/26/installing-pear-package-manager-on-wamp/

Answer (score 1):

you should be able to start it without editing php.ini using :

```
PATH/TO/php.exe -d phar.require_hash=0 PATH/TO/go-pear.phar
```