# Unable to install PEAR in PHP5

Tags: php, installation, pear

I tried to install PEAR in my php(XAMPP). But i get the following error..

```
> D:\xampp\php>go-pear
manifest cannot be larger than 100 MB in phar "D:\xampp\php\PEAR\go-pear.phar"PH
P Warning:  require_once(phar://go-pear.phar/index.php): failed to open stream:
phar error: invalid url or non-existent phar "phar://go-pear.phar/index.php" in
D:\xampp\php\PEAR\go-pear.phar on line 1236
Warning: require_once(phar://go-pear.phar/index.php): failed to open stream: pha
r error: invalid url or non-existent phar "phar://go-pear.phar/index.php" in D:\
xampp\php\PEAR\go-pear.phar on line 1236
Press any key to continue . . .**
```

I found the similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1652941/why-am-i-receiving-an-error-when-installing-pear). but still i get the same error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think XAMPP comes with PEAR installed. Try:

```
C:\XAMPP\PHP>pear upgrade PEAR
```